# How to check whether textView is being ellipsized Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I want to know how to check if my textView is being ellipsized..

That's my code snippet:

```
if(txtDescription.equals("")) {
    txtDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if(txtDescription.getLayout().getEllipsisCount(1)  > 0){ // this line is giving  java.lang.NullPointerException
    txtDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    txtDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But I always get a  java.lang.NullPointerException and I think it comes from getLayout() method..

That's the TextView's XML:

```
<TextView 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

`txtDescription.getLayout()` will return null because your textview layout is not finished.
Therefore you should check if the textView is being ellipsized inside `onGlobalLayout` method like this

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = textview.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
              Layout l = txtDescription.getLayout();
              if ( l != null){  
                 // check your textview is being ellipsized or not here
                 ...
              }          
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yesterday I have the same problem with **NullPointerException** while try to getLayout() and Alhamdulillah in documentation of TextView found that here is protected method with name **onLayout()** and this is called when TextView laid out and rendering is finished. After that I've **extended AppCompatTextView** in my case (or you can use TextView if yout not use appcompat library) and override it's **onLayout()** method, next cast the context to the Activity class and call some public method from that class.

```
class TextViewForLayout extends AppCompatTextView {
Context mContext;

void SetContext(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}

public TextViewForLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    SetContext(context);
}

public TextViewForLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    SetContext(context);
}

public TextViewForLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    SetContext(context);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (!changed) {
        ((MyActivity) mContext).someMethod();
    }
}
}
```

In your Activity class you need to have Ui thread handler and runnable as global variable as in my case (or use another way of using runnables by passing arguments)

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Handler mainHandler;
    Runnable addViewTo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        mainHandler = new Handler();

        addViewTo = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                // add single view or iterate throug List, Array or some Collections
                someParent.addView(childView);
           }
        };
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
        // do something with textView.getLayout().....
       // and post the addViewTo runnable to mainHadler
      // or the manipulations with UI will not shown
    }
}
```